# Simple example for decoupling UI and Calculation over network

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, servlets, soa

I am looking for a simple example,

1. UI is web based (accessed through browser over network)
2. Business logic (APIs) is deployed on a server. It is a printer management application.
3. Business logic will access external electronic printer & can access its state. Multiple printers can be connected to same server.
4. A real time graph of (or count) number of papers queued, printed etc needs to be displayed on UI.
5. User should be able to continue their session specific for a printer. Only one user can access a printer at a time (blocked for an user).
6. User can issue commands to printer over network (Tasks may take 10-15 mins to complete. Meanwhile, user will monitor progress).

I have already written program which handles Computer-Printer interaction using COM port. Local UI working fine. Now I want to have UI on web.

Please guide me which approach should I use to create such application. Although I have some experience with Java, I am new to Java EE or any network protocols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want information(about printers connected, papers remaining etc.,etc.) to be transferred from one system to another.
- You also want an exclusive lock per printer per user.

To be put in a short line
 - You want a printer server to provide printing services to a web application.

Have you heard of [webservices](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayk.html)??

Comment: Dont know much about web services. I also need user to issue commands to printer over network (Tasks may take 10-15 mins to complete. Meanwhile, user will monitor progress).

Do you recommend web services for this? Is there any specific design patterns I should look in specific?

Comment: @Tejasjain - You have to write programs that issue the individual commands to the printer either on the printer server or using a USB/SD Card on the printer.

These commands will make sense only in the server. Now you need to open up these programs to be called by separate server. This kind of programming is called [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)

Now you need to expose these APIs as services which your printer server offers. Webservices are the best way to do so.

Comment: I have already written program which handles Computer-Printer interaction using COM port. Local UI working fine. Now I want to have UI on web. Could you please provide a better URL for start learnig with

Answer (score 1):

Well,java EE 6 or 7 is your best option since you already have some background with Java. For the first issue (UI web based) I would recommend Javaserver Faces technology because it integrates perfectly with Java EE. For the second part, about the business logic (issue #2). I would recommend using Contexts and Dependency Injection (CDI) because they define a set of contextual services, provided by Java EE container (Server) and allows a lot of flexibility to integrate different components (not just EJBs). You will need to use stateful objects offered by Java EE to manage user specific sessions for a printer.
 To manage access & state of electronic printers, JPA is your best option since it will offer you container managed security and transaction services to persist and access electronic printer states. Singleton session bean with Interceptor business methods can be used for statistical purposes per application to address issue number 4.
 Java EE offers an Annotation type Concurrency Management which is quite simple to use. All you need to do is to annotate a business method (which performs some operation on the printer, in this case) with either @Lock(LockType.WRITE) or @Lock(LockType.READ) annotations to lock access to the printer during a call to such a method.
To get clarification on the above technologies I recommend reading Java EE 7 Recipes before embarking on your project. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help @Charles. Your answer made me more interested to learn JEE. May be I can understand most of your answer once I learn JEE. Thanks again :)